How can I reinitialize Slick carousel after appending new content via AJAX
I’m building a light fixture e-commerce site, HamptonLightings using the Slick library to display product images in a gallery. The gallery initializes correctly on page load, but when I append new content via AJAX, the newly added images don’t work with the Slick functionality. Here's the relevant code:
HTML:
<div id="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Light Fixture 1">
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Light Fixture 2">
    </div>
</div>

JavaScript:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery').slick(); // Initialize the gallery on page load
});

// AJAX to load more content
$.ajax({
    url: 'load-more.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#gallery-container').append(data);
        // The new content is added but the gallery isn’t reinitialized
    }
});

I tried calling .slick() after the content was appended, but it didn’t solve the problem. The new images appear as regular static images without the carousel functionality.
How can I ensure the gallery reinitializes properly after new content is appended?

Please [edit] your question to include the relevant html as a [mre]. If your ajax overwrites or recreates .gallery, then you'll likely have to re-initialize it.

If you're appending images to the gallery then you'd likely want to use Slick's API for that: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/  Manually modifying the DOM used by the plugin may just break it, or at least require that the whole thing be destroyed and re-initialized.

Thanks @David for the suggestion! I wasn't aware of Slick’s API for appending content. I'll check it out and see if using the API works better than directly modifying the DOM. If reinitializing isn’t ideal, I might try using the slickAdd method or reinitializing with the destroy/init methods. I’ll take a look at the documentation for more details

Thanks for the feedback @mykaf! I’ll add the relevant HTML to clarify the structure of the gallery. The .gallery element isn’t being overwritten by AJAX, but I’ll check if it’s recreated and try reinitializing after appending content.
